# sql server - data backing into local - is it necessary

Tags: sql-server, database, vb6

In all the years of my experience, I always connected to a database by creating a new connection using IP address, username and password. 
I recently joined a company where they use a desktop application written in **VB6** that has an **SQL** server backend. Here, the practice is, get a backup of the latest version of **SQL** server and name it as a different DB, use it for testing purposes.

We now have a issue where we have loads of these databases created by users and it needs cleanup.

My question: Is it possible to have a centralised database which exists remotely to which everyone connects and gets the data? what are the things that we need to keep in mind to achieve this goal, so everyone can have one single database to access to, where they can make the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ability to do that is really a functional and/or procedural issue. There's nothing technical that prevents you from having a single, shared database for dev/test. The challenge is, dev/test environments tend to be destructive and/or disruptive.

If you have a single DB used for all development and testing requirements, you'll probably get little to no work done. One dev modifying an object (SP, FN, table, view, etc...) can potentially break everyone else (or no one). A tester running stress tests will have everyone else getting mad about slow responses, timeouts, etc... Someone decides to test Always Encrypted or even sometime simpler like TDE can end up breaking everybody.

Dev environments almost always need their own sandbox before check-in. Checked in code/schema then get tested in a central environment that mimics prod before going to pre-prod that is (ideally) identical to prod. This is pretty basic though each team/company will have its variations.

One thing you could do right away is to automate taking a copy backup of the prod database so you drop a fresh .bak to a common location where everyone can grab from and restore to their own instance. This reduces the impact on your production system and reduces storage consumption. Another benefit is you remove all non-essential access to your production database - this is really, really important. Finally, once this is standard op, you can implement further controls or tasks in the future easily (e.g. restore to a secure instance, obfuscate/mask sensitive data, take new backup for dev/test use).

Comment: Many thanks @SQLmojoe. That was a great idea, taking a backup of PROD database. Also, there is a challenge here in my company to do that. We follow strict ISO guidelines and any copy of Prod Data has to be regularly cleaned up. Do you think, there will be any control on prod data when everybody in the team restores it in to their own instance??

Comment: If you own generating the "main" backup that everyone else uses, you already control the freshness of the distribution. Dev/test workstations are tougher to deal with. You can set domain policies and create jobs to periodically scan and report violations. All workstations should already have domain admins and probably other domain job/monitor accounts added to the host on provisioning (if not, work with your AD admins to do it). Suggest not auto-cleaning (refresh or delete) those using jobs. You run the risk of cleaning out a long running stress test and get people really mad.

Answer (score 1):

We've been using a single centralized dev/test environment for over a decade now, with up to 50 full time developers using it -- and I'd say it works quite fine. Most of the changes are new columns into tables and not that many developers are working with the same tables / modules at the same time, so it doesn't cause that much issues.

All our stored procedures / functions are renamed for each release separately (by adding a release number in the end), and installed automatically with compilation process, even for developers. For developers compilation, the version numbers also include the developers userid. This way changing stored procedures in development won't break the test environment, or the procedures other developers are using.

The biggest advantage of this is that we can use similarly sized databases for testing and production.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but it's usually not a good idea. It would be ok (and no more than ok) if all database access was inquiry only, but imagine the confusion that could arise if developer a fires in some updates to a table that developer be is writing a report for or if the DB was recovered in an uncontrolled manner. Development and test need a lot of managing and how many databases you need and where will depend on an analysis of your dev and test requrements.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers. We all had a discussion in our team and came up with a process that suits to our team:

- There is a master database backed up and restored from the most recent and     stable source
- Only QA team has got write access to this database
- Developers make their own test database using the Master backup
- If new data is required, write SQL scripts to add it
- Run unit & E2E tests on their copy
- Give the new tests and scripts to add new data (if any) to QA
- QA runs the tests and data scripts on the Master
- When the tests are passed, if there is a SQL update script, then QA restores the Master Database from the backup (to remove data changes made by running the tests), runs the SQL scripts to update the data then backs it up as the new Master
- Scripts are added to source control so we have a history

Note: As an extra safeguard we can keep a copy of the very first ever Master database somewhere else. So if anybody ever does something dumb and corrupts it, we can retrieve it and run all the SQL scripts to bring it up to date.